# Unable to retrieve Facebook Wall Posts

Tags: php, curl, facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook Graph API and my app credentials I am able to retrieve a valid token:

```
171372936213670|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-650901429|x_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx
```

The code I use to retrieve Wall Posts:

```
function getFbWallPosts($user, $limit=5) {
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $token = $ci->facebook->getAccessToken();
    $param = array(
        'access_token' => $token, 
        'limit' => $limit,
        );
    $posts = $ci->facebook->api("$user/feed", 'GET', $param);

    return $posts; 
}
```

The function always returns an empty jSON result:

```
{"data":[]}
```

Also tested directly accessing Wall Posts using cURL:

```
function fbrequest($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}
```

...to no avail.

EDIT: Also tried using file_get_contents but it also returns empty jSON:

```
function fbrequest($url) {
   $output = file_get_contents($url);
   return $output;
}
```

Tried pasting the request string directly on my browser (without a user logged in to Facebook):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/AValidFacebookUsername/feed?access_token=171372936213670|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-650901429|x_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx
```

...successfully returns a jSON string with all the posts

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that there is nothing wrong with the codes I'm writing. The problem is with how I interpreted the process and, eventually, the result. There are pre-requisites on accessing other user's data on FB and in case of group pages, one of them is that the user requesting the data MUST BE A FAN OF THAT GROUP.

Silly me...

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
function curl($url){
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $content;
}
```

If no luck, maybe Apache is not compiled with SSL support.

Comment: Didn't work. The site is running on HostGator and we have our own SSL-enabled domain.

Comment: curl
cURL support  enabled
cURL Information libcurl/7.21.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8q zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5

Comment: openssl
OpenSSL support  enabled
OpenSSL Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8q 2 Dec 2010

Comment: My bad, it is still returning **{"data":[]}**, guess you already checked $params to see if it is correct? I don't know if FB allows non-secure http for this but just to be sure try it that way. Could be your IP is temporarily blocked if you are on shared hosting (there is probably some limit on FB for API).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I won't be a able to initiate my app if the IP is blocked.

Comment: Also, I tried accessing the URL on my browser without the token and returned a successful result:

https://graph.facebook.com/dealspotphilippines/feed

Comment: Well I got just "data", you are getting result because you are logged in perhaps, try accessing from other browser, and you will see what I am talking about. Check you tokens and everything (from other brower/session).